# Returning a function with a closure

Tags: f#

The following code:

```
let CreateFunc=
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () -> counter := !counter + 1; !counter

let f1 = CreateFunc
let f2 = CreateFunc

printfn "%d" (f1())
printfn "%d" (f1())
printfn "%d" (f2())
printfn "%d" (f2())
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
```

So, basically, what we see here is f1 and f2 being the same function - as they're obviously sharing the same instance of 'counter'.

The expected output is:

```
1
2
1
2
```

QUESTION: Shouldn't f1 and f2 be two separate instances? After all they are created by the two different calls to 'CreateFunc'???

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let CreateFunc() =
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () -> counter := !counter + 1; !counter

let f1 = CreateFunc()
let f2 = CreateFunc()

printfn "%d" (f1())
printfn "%d" (f1())
printfn "%d" (f2())
printfn "%d" (f2())
```

Output is

```
1
2
1
2
```

Explanation:

In your original solution, `CreateFunc` was a function, but always the same function (`CreateFunc`, `f1` and `f2` were all synonyms, all pointing to the same function). In my solution `CreateFunc` is a function which returns a **new** function whenever it is called, thus each function has its own state (i.e. `counter`).

In short: the original `CreateFunc` was a value, always the same value.

Comment: @swapneel - `:=` is the way you assign a value to a reference cell (created with `ref 0` in this case). This code uses `!counter` to read the value out of the reference cell.

Comment: To elaborate @JoelMueller's answer: since regular let-bindings are immutable, when you do want to use mutable bindings (and `let mutable` has its disadvantages), you use `ref` types, which are a bit similar to C/C++ pointers (only a bit). To get their value you can use the `!` prefix operator (like in the code `!counter`) and to assign you can use the binary operator `:=` (line in the code `counter := !counter + 1`). *Note*: since `counter := !counter + 1` is common, there is an `incr` function (used `incr counter`) which increments the `int ref` by one.

Comment: To elaborate to @Ramon Snir's answer, ordinary mutables are not allowed in closures, so ref cells must be used here.